# Web Methods Package Deleted Recovery

Tags: integration, webmethods

I am new to Web Methods and I was trying to subscribe a package from a remote IS to my IS. The package name which I imported had the same name as one of the existing packages in my IS and the new package replaced the existing one. I know that the original package could be recovered by using the recover package option but I missed that step and no packages are shown in the recover package option. Is there any other way to recover the previous package? Help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you used to bring the package from your remote server.

If you used webMethods' archiving feature, which created a zip file in `/IntegrationServer/Replicate/outbound` and then you copied the zip file to your local server under `/IntegrationServer/Replicate/inbound` then the original local package will automatically get archived in the `/IntegrationServer/Replicate/Archive` folder.

In the Archive folder, all the zip files have a timestamp, remove the timestamp and copy it to  `/IntegrationServer/Replicate/inbound` of your local server and then install it through the IS web administration console.

If you simply copied the entire package folder and then pasted the package folder into your local server then you definitely lost your previous work.

Hope it helps,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you follow any archival policy. At many places there is an archival process which is used to archive all the packages. If no, Then I dont think we can recover it. If IS is hosted on your system then you can try system restore to a previous date. I have never tried it but might work.

Comment: The IS is not hosted in my own system so I believe I have lost the package.